# JS load order with jQuery on load inside a function that executes immediately

Tags: jquery

Can you do this?

```
var myFunction = function(){
    $(function(){
        // jQuery code here
        $("#myField").hide();
    })    
}();
```

I had some code like this which worked fine almost everywhere but then I discovered it only worked about 80% of the time in FF 9.0.1. The fix was to do this:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    $(function(){
        // jQuery code here
        $("#myField").hide();
    })    
};
myFunction();
```

Now I'm a bit puzzled why this was necessary

EDIT:
I can see this is a bit confusing. Maybe what I should have done would have been this instead:

```
var myFunction = function(){ 
    // jQuery code here
    $("#myField").hide();       
};

$(function(){
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Yep, you can do this, but why?

Comment: I'm using namespaces because there are many functions running on the same page. This is just the smallest fragment needed to demonstrate the problem. There are over 3000 lines of code altogether

Comment: Still, the first snippet should work, perhaps the error is hidden somewhere in the other 2900 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not correctly defining the function and then putting jQuery code, when the `JavaScript` parser reads you code it will ignore the var definition and execute the `jQuery` that you defined on document ready.  In case you don't know:

```
 $(function(){})
 // is equivalent to 
 $(document).ready(function(){}).
```

The best option for you would be to create a function like:

```
 function myFunction(){  

    $("#myField").hide();

 }

 $(function(){

    //after whenever you want it do 
    myFunction();

 })
```

Comment: I realised this myself and edited my post. Then I spotted your answer. I think this is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var myFunction;
(myFunction = function(){
  $(function(){
    // jQuery code here
    $("#myField").hide();
  })    
}) ();
```

Comment: That's effectively the same code the OP already has, it won't change anything.

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary here, a variable assignment is already an expression

Comment: of course you are right, I meant to write it the way it's done now

Comment: Your way of writing it now is exactly the same as the op's first snippet

Comment: it isn't. The OP's snippet sets the value of `myFunction` to undefined.

Comment: @wroniasty I see, so it's not exactly the same but effectively the same

Comment: @Esailija not unless he's planning to use `myFunction` later on (which IMO is a good assumption)

Comment: @wroniasty that would be weird but still possible, his second snippet achieves that